# Where is the last vote stored?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fivestar

I'm using FiveStars module and I'm modifying the code. I need to get the last vote of a user for a specific node.

I'm sure that the module stores it, because it displays the stars the user previously selected, when he logs in and re-visits the node.

But I'm not able to find this in the code. (I only found the average vote for a node, and the count of nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `fivestar_get_votes()` in fivestar.module. To get the votes for, say, user 1 on node 34, you'd do `fivestar_get_votes('node', 34, 'vote', 1)`. Alternatively, take a look at the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/node/68851), which `fivestar_get_votes()` uses.

Comment: The votes are stored from Voting API. I would use the Fivestar functions if there isn't any other module that allows users to vote.

Comment: Great thanks, it worked. Fivestars works great, and it is easy to fix to assign custom points for each star...